# loong variable grep output same input variable

Tags: bash, grep

i have a long variable and i will search with grep, when i use |grep rc

then output bash the same line who is $crf

i want search rc= set the value after = to variable

```
crf="cabac=1 / ref=5 / deblock=1:-3:-3 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=umh / subme=7 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.15 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=0 / chroma_qp_offset=-3 / threads=16 / lookahead_threads=2 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=24 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=19.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00"
rc=$(echo $crf |grep rc=)
```

output is same from input $crf

Comment: Do you know what `grep` does?

Comment: BTW, `echo $crf` is itself buggy; see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I have tag name=value pairs in my data I find it best to first create an array of the tag names to values (`f[]` below) and then I can just access the values by their names, e.g.:

```
$ crf='cabac=1 / ref=5 / deblock=1:-3:-3 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=umh / subme=7 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.15 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=0 / chroma_qp_offset=-3 / threads=16 / lookahead_threads=2 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=24 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=19.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00'

$ echo "$crf" | awk -v tag='rc' -F' / |=' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) f[$i]=$(i+1); print f[tag]}'
crf

$ echo "$crf" | awk -v tag='ip_ratio' -F' / |=' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) f[$i]=$(i+1); print f[tag]}'
1.40

$ rc=$(echo "$crf" | awk -v tag='rc' -F' / |=' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) f[$i]=$(i+1); print f[tag]}')                     $ echo "$rc"
crf
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `grep`. The command [grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) will search each line for match and if found, will print that line. Since yours is a single-line string, it will always print you the whole line.

Instead, you can use `awk` to split by `rc=` and then `cut` to keep only the value:

```
rc=$(awk -F'rc=' '{ print $2 }' <<< $crf | cut -d' ' -f1)
```

Part by part:

- `awk -F'rc=' '{ print $2 }' <<< $crf` it splits the string `crf` by the delimiter `rc=` and prints the second substring. That part will start with the value assigned to `rc=`
- `| cut -d' ' -f1` it splits the substring above by space () and keeps only the first element, i.e. the value you're looking for.

Comment: `awk -F'rc=' '{ print $2 }' | cut -d' ' -f1` = `awk -F'rc=' '{ sub(/ .*/,"",$2); print $2 }'` or `awk -F'rc=' '{ split($2,f,/[ ]/); print f[1] }'`. Quote your shell variables though - `"$crf"`, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.